# Simple http operator headers value jinja template not supported

Tags: jinja2, airflow

I am trying to use templating in headers value of my http request using my custom http operator ( Extends simpleHttpOperator ). Seems like templating is supported only in data field. How can implemente the same in headers field. I wanted to pass authorization header templated. Please find my code below.

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.configuration import conf
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.auth_plugins import SipAuthOperator
from airflow.operators.util_plugins import AuthUtility


DEFAULT_VERSION = '2.0'

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False

}

DAG_ID = 'test_dag'
dag = DAG(DAG_ID, default_args=default_args,
          schedule_interval=None,
          catchup=False)
dag.doc_md = __doc__

auth_endpoint = conf['auth_apis']['authenticate_end_point']

def inspect_params(**context):
    token = context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key='JWT_TOKEN',value='helloooo'
                                       )
    print(token)

test_operator = PythonOperator(dag=dag,task_id='init_api',
                                       python_callable=inspect_params,
                                       provide_context=True, )

# data={'token':'{{task_instance.xcom_pull(key=\'JWT_TOKEN\')}}'}
# {'Authorization':'Bearer '+'{{task_instance.xcom_pull(key=\'JWT_TOKEN\')}}'
http_operator = SipAuthOperator( dag=dag,task_id='authenticate_api',http_conn_id='auth_api',endpoint=auth_endpoint,headers={'token':'{{task_instance.xcom_pull(key=\'JWT_TOKEN\')}}'})

test_operator >> http_operator
```

Header value coming as `{'token': "{{task_instance.xcom_pull(key='JWT_TOKEN')}}"}` which is not as desred. If I put the same value in data field it works fine as expected. Is jinja templating supported on headers ? Any work around for this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `template_fields` attribute in an operator determines which parameters can be templated. For example, in the original [SimpleHttpOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.3/airflow/operators/http_operator.py#L57) you can see the following

```
class SimpleHttpOperator(BaseOperator):
    ...
    template_fields = ('endpoint', 'data',)
    ...
```

Which is why `endpoint` and `data` are supported template fields. Similarly in your custom operator, you'll want to include `header`.

```
class SipAuthOperator(SimpleHttpOperator):
    ...
    template_fields = ('endpoint', 'data', 'header',)
    ...
```